# jquery file upload plugin template engine?

Tags: jquery, html, jst

I got the jquery file upload plugin working on our site: 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine

However it uses a java script template language that was tied in with jquery at one time, but has been discontinued and removed from jquery. The guy I work with wants me to remove the template engine part of the plugin and write it in straight javascript instead. Since the template language is not supported he is not comfortable with having it in our code.

I found here with where the documentation talks about creating your own template engine in straight JS which I guess is what I need to do.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine

I am not sure if learning more about the template language may also help me, which I had looked at a few sites on that.

I am on vacation at the moment, but when I get back in a week, I need to start working on this.

I have written a fair amount of javascript and jquery stuff, but I am not always super familiar with all the idioms and in some cases I copy and paste code samples.

This is the code example for your own template engine. I guess it sets up callbacks .. 
I will basically have to cut and paste it and see if it works. I did try that, but initially it didn't work for me.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    uploadTemplateId: null,
    downloadTemplateId: null,
    uploadTemplate: function (o) {
        var rows = $();
        $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
            var row = $('<tr class="template-upload fade">' +
             '<td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>' +
             '<td class="name"></td>' +
             '<td class="size"></td>' +
             (file.error ? '<td class="error" colspan="2"></td>' :
                    '<td><div class="progress">' +
                        '<div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div></td>' +
                        '<td class="start"><button>Start</button></td>'
              ) + '<td class="cancel"><button>Cancel</button></td></tr>');
            row.find('.name').text(file.name);
            row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
            if (file.error) {
               row.find('.error').text(
                  locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error
               );
            }
            rows = rows.add(row);
         });
        return rows;
    },
   downloadTemplate: function (o) {
      var rows = $();
      $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
        var row = $('<tr class="template-download fade">' +
            (file.error ? '<td></td><td class="name"></td>' +
                '<td class="size"></td><td class="error" colspan="2"></td>' :
                    '<td class="preview"></td>' +
                        '<td class="name"><a></a></td>' +
                        '<td class="size"></td><td colspan="2"></td>'
            ) + '<td class="delete"><button>Delete</button> ' +
                '<input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1"></td></tr>');
        row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
        if (file.error) {
            row.find('.name').text(file.name);
            row.find('.error').text(
                locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error
            );
        } else {
            row.find('.name a').text(file.name);
            if (file.thumbnail_url) {
                row.find('.preview').append('<a><img></a>')
                    .find('img').prop('src', file.thumbnail_url);
                row.find('a').prop('rel', 'gallery');
            }
            row.find('a').prop('href', file.url);
            row.find('.delete button')
                .attr('data-type', file.delete_type)
                .attr('data-url', file.delete_url);
        }
        rows = rows.add(row);
    });
    return rows;
}
```

});

---

Here is some working piece of code that I have which gets called after the file load completes. Does this need to be combined with the above code to work ?

Why is this code in a sort of annonymous function of the form
$(function() { $("#fileupload").fileupload(){ ...

The other code example is not in an annonymous function .. maybe it doesn’t really matter ?

```
$(function () {
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {                          
         var str = "<h4>" + data.result.name + '  -  ' + data.result.text_status + "</h4>";
         console.log(str);
         <% if @ie %>
           data.context.html(str);
           $("#files_tbody").append("<tr>" + str + "</tr>");
         <% else %>
           data.context.html(str);
         <% end %>
    }
  });
});
```

I tried having both of those code segments seperate as shown and my upload does not work, I tried combining them as below and that did not work either .. 
Any advice on what I am missing or where to look would be appreciated ..

Using the code block below I get the error on file load in firebug saying:

TypeError: $("#fileupload").fileupload is not a function
    downloadTemplate: function (o) {

And also:

TypeError: document.getElementById(a) is null
    ...urn{"\n":"\n","\r":"\r","\t":"\t"," ":" "}[a]||"\"+a;if(c)return c==="="?"'+...

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
   dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {                          
         var str = "<h4>" + data.result.name + '  -  ' + data.result.text_status + "</h4>";
         console.log(str);
         <% if @ie %>
           data.context.html(str);
           $("#files_tbody").append("<tr>" + str + "</tr>");
         <% else %>
           data.context.html(str);
         <% end %>
    }
uploadTemplateId: null,
downloadTemplateId: null,
uploadTemplate: function (o) {
    var rows = $();
    $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
        var row = $('<tr class="template-upload fade">' +
            '<td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>' +
            '<td class="name"></td>' +
            '<td class="size"></td>' +
            (file.error ? '<td class="error" colspan="2"></td>' :
                    '<td><div class="progress">' +
                        '<div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div></td>' +
                        '<td class="start"><button>Start</button></td>'
            ) + '<td class="cancel"><button>Cancel</button></td></tr>');
        row.find('.name').text(file.name);
        row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
        if (file.error) {
            row.find('.error').text(
                locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error
            );
        }
        rows = rows.add(row);
    });
    return rows;
},
downloadTemplate: function (o) {
    var rows = $();
    $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
        var row = $('<tr class="template-download fade">' +
            (file.error ? '<td></td><td class="name"></td>' +
                '<td class="size"></td><td class="error" colspan="2"></td>' :
                    '<td class="preview"></td>' +
                        '<td class="name"><a></a></td>' +
                        '<td class="size"></td><td colspan="2"></td>'
            ) + '<td class="delete"><button>Delete</button> ' +
                '<input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1"></td></tr>');
        row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
        if (file.error) {
            row.find('.name').text(file.name);
            row.find('.error').text(
                locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error
            );
        } else {
            row.find('.name a').text(file.name);
            if (file.thumbnail_url) {
                row.find('.preview').append('<a><img></a>')
                    .find('img').prop('src', file.thumbnail_url);
                row.find('a').prop('rel', 'gallery');
            }
            row.find('a').prop('href', file.url);
            row.find('.delete button')
                .attr('data-type', file.delete_type)
                .attr('data-url', file.delete_url);
        }
        rows = rows.add(row);
    });
    return rows;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'TypeError: $("#fileupload").fileupload' message probably means that you load jQuery in 'no-conflict' mode: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
This is done e.g. by wordpress engine.
A solution is suggested here (from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

Reverts the $ alias and then creates and executes a function to
provide the $ as a jQuery alias inside the functions scope. Inside the
function the original $ object is not available. This works well for
most plugins that don't rely on any other library.

> ```
> jQuery.noConflict();
> (function($) { 
>   $(function() {
>     // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
>   });
> })(jQuery);
> // other code using $ as an alias to the other library
> ```

Comment: Great! I tried to use fileupload in a facebook app, and this was the trick for me there. Thanks.